# Calculate minimum of two independent and piecewise defined function random variable

Tags: math, distribution, probability-density, cdf, stochastic

I want to calculate Cumulative distribution function of Y, when Y is a Random Variable (Y=min{X,X'}) and X is a piecewise defined function Random variable. CDF of X is something like this code:

```
if (0<x<A) then FX = B(x)
 else if (A<x<A^2) then FX = D(x)
```

I know that FY=1-((1-FX)^2). But it doesn't work when X is a piecewise defined function. How can I calculate FY?

Comment: What is a "multidisciplinary function"? Do you mean "multivariable function"? What is `X`? `A`? `B`? `D`? `F`? You really need to explain what you mean rather than dropping symbols and hoping that we can guess your meaning. In any event, this is off-topic in Stack Overflow since it is more about mathematics then computing.

Comment: Perhaps by "multidisciplinary" you mean "piecewise defined"?  If so, how can two pieces have the same defining condition (`(0<x<A)`?) That looks like a typo. If this is what you mean, then mathematically I don't see what the problem is. There is nothing about `G(y) = 1 - (1 - F(x)))^2 (Where `G` is the cdf of `Y`) which depends on `F` not being piecewise defined. That bit of probability theory makes no assumption on `F` (beyond that it is a valid CDF). What do you  mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Thank U for ur response. 1. Yes exactly I mean that X is a piecewise defined function and consequently Y will be too. 2. range of x was a mistake. I edited that. 3. I compared CDF of simulated data on matlab with Function that I calculated by G(y) = 1 - (1 - F(x)))^2, and they weren't same. They had small differences in the middle of plot.

Comment: Round-off error? Sampling error if you are doing a simulation? Perhaps there is a bug in your simulation or in your formula for `F`. Mathematically, the fact that `F` is piecewise-defined isn't relevant.

Comment: Without knowing what the functions are and how the simulation was done, it is impossible to know whether or not there is anything surprising about the image that you posted. A curve generated by Monte Carlo methods almost never matches a theoretical curve.

Comment: Thank you for your response. and you mean I should explain all functions here? I'm sure simulation is correct. I 'm going to check functions again :(

Comment: Explaining what the cdf of `X` is wouldn't hurt. If it is piecewise defined, then the cdf of `Y` would similarly be piecewise defined, though I don't see how `1-((1-B(x))(1-D(x)))` could be one of the pieces.